# Stop observable stream of shared data service Angular

Tags: angular, observable, subscription

I have this service to share data between components of my application :

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { BehaviorSubject } from 'rxjs/BehaviorSubject';

@Injectable()
export class DataService {

    private source = new BehaviorSubject<any>('');
    data = this.source.asObservable();

    constructor() { }

    update(values: any) {
        this.source.next(values);
    }
}
```

From a component, I update data like this :

```
this.dataSvc.update(this.data);
```

Assuming this.data is an object.

From another component, I subscribe at the service

```
this.dataSvc.data.subscribe(
    data => let object = data,
    error => console.log(error),
    () => console.log('complete')
);
```

The complete method is never called. 
How I can call the complete method and stop subscribing ?
I tried to add `this.source.complete()` just after next in service. It doesn't work

Thanks

Comment: try `this.dataSvc.data.take(1).subscribe(...)`

Comment: I can't use take. It's note a function

Comment: you need to import the take operator... `import 'rxjs/add/operator/take'`

Comment: It works but, I can stop emit into my service ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The reason the Observable never completes is that you are never unsubscribing from it.

You could use an operator like [`takeUntil`](http://reactivex.io/documentation/operators/takeuntil.html) (if there is a certain condition you want to unsubscribe on), but I have a feeling you just need to clean up your subscription when the component is destroyed. Here are a couple options for how to do that:

**You can use the `ngOnDestroy` lifecycle hook to unsubscribe from this subscription when the component is destroyed.**

Try this:

```
subscription: Subscription;

/* using ngOnInit life cycle hook for the example, 
   but you could assign the subscription anywhere */
ngOnInit() { 
  this.subscription = this.dataSvc.data.subscribe( //.. )
}

ngOnDestroy() {
  this.subscription.unsubscribe();
}
```

The problem is that you are setting up your subscription, but never cleaning it up, so the Observable never "completes". The above code will fix that problem.

**Alternatively, if you only need the data in your template and not in your component class, you could use the `async` pipe.**

In your `component.ts` file:

```
data$: Observable<Data>;
ngOnInit() {
  this.data$ = this.dataSvc.data;
}
```

Then in your template:

```
 <p> {{ data$ | async }} </p>
```

When your component gets destroyed, Angular will handle all the clean up for you :)

Here are some links about [life cycle hooks](https://angular.io/guide/lifecycle-hooks), the [`unsubscribe`](http://reactivex.io/rxjs/class/es6/Subscription.js~Subscription.html#instance-method-unsubscribe) method, and the [`async` pipe](https://angular.io/api/common/AsyncPipe).

Comment: Thnks, I will try

Comment: Okay - let me know if it works or if your question still needs answering

Comment: Happy to help, consider “accepting” the answer by clicking the check mark so others know that you’re question has been answered. And welcome to SO :)